# Why maven-surefire plugin running twice?

Tags: java, maven, groovy, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a Java application using the Maven build tool and using Spock framework for unit test cases.

I am upgrading my Groovy version 2.5.7 to 3.0.19 and Spock version 1.3-groovy-2.5 to 2.3-groovy-3.0.

properties:

```xml
<mavenSurefirePluginVersion>3.0.0-M4</mavenSurefirePluginVersion>
<gmaven-plugin.version>1.5</gmaven-plugin.version>
<gmaven-runtime.version>1.5</gmaven-runtime.version>
<java.version>11</java.version>
<mavenCompilerPluginVersion>3.8.0</mavenCompilerPluginVersion>
```

Below are the plugins:

```xml
<plugins>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gmaven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-2.0</artifactId>
                <version>${gmaven-runtime.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                <version>${groovyVersion}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${mavenSurefirePluginVersion}</version>
        <configuration>
            <properties>
                <property>
                    <name>listener</name>
                    <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
            <useFile>false</useFile>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                <version>${mavenSurefirePluginVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
                <version>${mavenSurefirePluginVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Added dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

While doing `maven clean compile install` in IntelliJ, I get below logs

```
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.5:testCompile (default) @ test-base ---
[INFO] Compiled 17 Groovy classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) @ test-base ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------

--- running tests----
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 28, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Its an multi module application and **test-base** is a sub module and which having below plugin:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mavenCompilerPluginVersion}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</generatedSourcesDirectory>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Here, why am I seeing [INFO] Tests run: two times? One with 0 tests run and the other one with actual tests run. How to remove the first test results?

Comment: does your project have multiple modules? (in POM)
btw: when you call `mvn` with the goal `install`, `compile` is included - will probably trigger compile twice, but that should not impact the tests. Please notice that the first occurence in the logs shows 0 tests run, but the second shows 28.

Comment: yes, its an multi module application. But in earlier version, this issue not happened. Is there anyway to show only second occurence?

Comment: Updated sub module plugin

Comment: Why you add dependencies `surefire-junit47` and `surefire-junit-platform` to `maven-surefire-plugin`? Do you use JUnit4 and JUnit5 in one project?

Comment: Based on what I can see here you don't have an engine of junit jupiter anywhere also why using an old versions for maven-surefire-plugin ... etc. furtherrmore you should define the junit jupiter part via BOM ...

Comment: which JUnit version do you want to use? 4 or 5? (If you don't know exactly, just add one import of an `@Test` annotation here, probably the package name helps us.)

Comment: ```surefire-junit47``` plugin is there from very long in my project. I have added ```surefire-junit-platform``` to run the unit tests as Junit in intelliJ. Without this intelliJ not picking the test cases to run. I am not having any Junit test cases in my project. Only using spock. 

Now I tried to removed both ```surefire-junit47 and surefire-junit-platform``` plugins and able to run the test cases in intelliJ and also only able to see this ```"[INFO] Tests run: 28"``` occurence.

Comment: I was faced ```java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/discovery/NestedClassSelector``` while running test. After adding `` junit-platform-engine``` dependency, its solved. Why I need to add Junit dependency in spock environment?